# Data Flow Task - Set two User Date Variables as Parameters

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing

I am creating an SSIS package that will run each month.  This particular stored procedure needs to run for one week at a time since the data returned is very large.

I have set up my stored procedure to with two parameters: @StartDT and @EndDT.  I created two SSIS variables: StartDT and Wk1EndDT (I'll create the other start and end dates for the weeks once I get this one working).

StartDT has this expression:

```
(DT_DATE)((DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(DATEADD("mm", -1, GETDATE())) + "-" +RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("mm", -1, GETDATE())),2)+"-01")
```

Wk1EndDT has this expression:

```
DATEADD("DD",7, @[User::StartDT])
```

I'm using a DataFlow task with a SQL command text of:

```
EXECUTE dbo.uspUploadWk1 ?,?
```

When I go to preview the results, I receive the following error message:
There was an error displaying the preview.
No value given for one or more required parameters. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

I have the parameters set like this:
[image: Parameters]

I am not sure why this isn't working.  I've searched all over and have not found an answer.  I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: `EXECUTE dbo.uspUploadWk1 ?, ?` is how you should be specifying your parameters

Comment: @billinkc I am doing that.  I made a mistake when typing it out.  I'll update it. I'm receiving an error message: There was an error displaying the preview. No value given for one or more required parameters. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an OLE DB Connection Manager, the Mappings tab should be using a zero based ordinal system on the Parameters column. Yes, it defaults to naming them as Parameter0, Parameter1, etc but for an OLE DB connection manager, you'll use the ordinal position of the question marks, `?`, starting at zero.

For ODBC, it becomes a 1 based counting but still uses `?` as the parameter place holder.

ADO.NET uses named parameters so we'd match `EXECUTE dbo.uspUploadWk1 @Parameter0, @Parameter1` but the ADO.NET source component doesn't support parameterization

[Reference on parameters and mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/parameters-and-return-codes-in-the-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014) for Execute SQL Task but the syntax remains the same for Data Flow Task components